# My div is stretching on large screens in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

My image overlay is stretching on large screen. I have tried max-width but no solution. max-width destroys responsiveness on small screens.

I am trying to add transition on image so overlay will come when I will hover on image but issue is that img-overlay is stretched out on large screens

[image]

```css
.head-txt {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}

.resource-img-height {
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.font-color {
  color: black;
}

.font-size-resourse {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.resourse-book-txt-width {
  width: 250px;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  /* max-width: 97%; */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.book-img-div:hover .img-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-12 mt-1" style="background-color: white;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 img-div-pad-right img-div-pad-left book-img-div"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid resource-img-height" alt="">
      <div class="img-overlay vw-100"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto">
      <h5 class="font-color mt-1">Book</h5>
      <h1 class="font-color mt-1">Product Leadership</h1>
      <p class="font-color mt-3 resourse-book-txt-width font-size-resourse">How Top Product Managers Launch Awesome Products and Build Successful Teams.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 img-div-pad-right img-div-pad-left book-img-div"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid resource-img-height" alt="">
      <div class="img-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto">
      <h5 class="font-color mt-1">Book</h5>
      <h1 class="font-color mt-1">Product Leadership</h1>
      <p class="font-color mt-3 resourse-book-txt-width font-size-resourse">How Top Product Managers Launch Awesome Products and Build Successful Teams.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a few extra CSS image parameters (see below).

Overlay CSS parameters are fine (but set opacity: 0).

We think that the DIV placements are out of sequence, as the text needs to be inside so it can stack (see example below).

The class col-lg-3 may (or may not) need changed after its placed inside all of that.

We used JS comments to make it a bit easier to see arrangement of closing DIV's.

Example below uses only one (col-lg-3) DIV sets with image.

```
 .resource-img-height {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  /*--height: auto;--*/
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
 }

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 }

 <div class="col-lg-3 img-div-pad-right img-div-pad-left book-img-div"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" class="img-fluid resource-img-height" alt="">
    <div class="img-overlay vw-100">
        <div class="col-lg-3 my-auto">
            <h5 class="font-color mt-1">Book</h5>
            <h1 class="font-color mt-1">Product Leadership</h1>
            <p class="font-color mt-3 resourse-book-txt-width font-size-resourse">How Top Product Managers Launch Awesome Products and Build Successful Teams.</p>
        </div><!--// End text-->
    </div><!--// End overlay-->
</div><!--// End column container and image-->
```